# DOM multiple IDs with the same function

Tags: javascript, html, function, addeventlistener

How to make the IDs to use the same function?.
I'm planning to make more element with the same function, but don't want to make more functions.

```
 var star_1 = document.getElementById("star1");
    var star_2 = document.getElementById("star2");

    var toggle = false;

    favToggle = function() {


        if (toggle === true) {
            star_1.src = "assets/svg/checked-star.svg";

        } else {
            star_1.src = "assets/svg/unchecked-star.svg";
        }

        toggle = !toggle;
    }

     favToggle1 = function() {


        if (toggle === true) {
            star_2.src = "assets/svg/checked-star.svg";

        } else {
            star_2.src = "assets/svg/unchecked-star.svg";
        }

        toggle = !toggle;
    }

    star_1.addEventListener("click", favToggle);
    star_2.addEventListener("click", favToggle1);
```

Comment: use a class instead, then you can loop through the elements and apply the event to each of them

Comment: The event handler is provided an Event Object. You can use the `target` property of the event to discover which element was clicked because it is the  `target` of the event. This allows you to have one function that "toggles" to target. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Comment: Also can you show the html - I don't think your event will work anyway as you don't seem to toggle any of the previous stars - surely if this is a rating system, you need to toggle all the stars up to the clicked one.  Do you even need js complicating things? https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

Comment: it's already answered, but here are the rest of the html: https://codepen.io/nodevillivedon/pen/WmEVYE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
// Number of stars you have
const nbStars = 4;

// An array where we keep the toggle state of each star
const toggles = [];

// Deal with the stars. One by one
for (let i = 0; i < nbStars; i += 1) {
  // Setup the initial state of the toggle
  toggles.push(false);

  const star = document.getElementById(`star${i + 1}`);

  star.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (toggles[i] === true) {
      star.innerHTML = 'assets/svg/checked-star.svg';
    } else {
      star.innerHTML = 'assets/svg/unchecked-star.svg';
    }

    // Change the state of the toggle for that particular star
    toggles[i] = !toggles[i];
  });
}
```

```css
.star {
  height: 5em;
  width 5em;
  background-color: #444444;
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="star1" class="star"></div>
<div id="star2" class="star"></div>
<div id="star3" class="star"></div>
<div id="star4" class="star"></div>
```

---

An alternative using @brk nice idea about `querySelectorAll`

```js
const toggles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="star"]')).map((x, xi) => {
  x.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (toggles[xi] === true) {
      x.innerHTML = 'assets/svg/checked-star.svg';
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = 'assets/svg/unchecked-star.svg';
    }

    // Change the state of the toggle for that particular star
    toggles[xi] = !toggles[xi];
  });

  // Setup the initial state of the toggle
  return false;
});
```

```css
.star {
  height: 5em;
  width 5em;
  background-color: #444444;
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="star1" class="star"></div>
<div id="star2" class="star"></div>
<div id="star3" class="star"></div>
<div id="star4" class="star"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use wild card selector. In this example it is selecting all elements with `id` starting with `star`. Then iterating through each of them and adding event listener to it

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='star']").forEach(function(elem) {
  this.addEventListener("click", favToggle);
})

function favToggle() {
  console.log('Button clicked')
}
```

```html
<button id='star1'>Button 1</button>
<button id='star2'>Button 2</button>
<button id='star3'>Button 3</button>
<button id='star4'>Button 4</button>
```

Comment: Good idea about the `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll()` to get both `"#star1,#star2"`. And then use `forEach()` and `addEventListener()` to each element.

```
var stars = document.querySelectorAll("#star1,#star2");
stars.forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if (toggle === true) {
        this.src = "assets/svg/checked-star.svg";
    } else {
        this.src = "assets/svg/unchecked-star.svg";
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
  })
})
```

Comment: @epascarello but in his code he didn't mentioned that. His code is showing he want to have only one toggle variable

Comment: ah, looks like you are right.... I thought it was not shared (FYI, not the downvote)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of writing a function is in order to be able to easily re-use the functionality it provides. You can access outside variables in your function by passing them as arguments. See the comments in the code below:

```js
//Create your vars
var star_1 = document.querySelector('#star1');
var star_2 = document.querySelector('#star2');
var toggle = false;

//Define the function to accept a parameter (a star)
function favToggle(star) {
  if (toggle === true) {
    star.src = "assets/svg/checked-star.svg";
  } else {
    star.src = "assets/svg/unchecked-star.svg";
  }
  toggle = !toggle;

  //Log some info so we can see it's working as expected
  console.log(`${star.id} src property is now: ${star.src}`);
  console.log(`toggle is now: ${toggle}`);
}

//Add your event listeners by passing a reference to the star (this)
star_1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  favToggle(this);
});
star_2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  favToggle(this);
});
```

```html
<div id="star1">star1</div>
<div id="star2">star2</div>
```